# exceptions not caught in iOS simulator from extern "C" block with target 7

Tags: ios, c, ios7, exception

I have c++ code in my iOS project, and in the parts wrapped with extern "C" {}, exceptions that I throw are not being caught, and crashes the application.

- this happens only when project deployment target is set to 7.0 and above.
- happens only in the xcode simulator, works well on devices with iOS7.

for example, this code crashes and doesn't get to the catch clause, when calling func1():

```
extern "C" {

    bool func2(){
        throw OpenSSLException("abc"); //crashes here
    }

    bool func1(){
        try {
            func2(); //calls func2 and crashes
        } catch (OpenSSLException& e) {
            //we never get here
        }
    }

}
```

crashes with: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type OpenSSLException: abc

Could be related to the fact that I'm catching c++ exceptions from a code wrapped with extern C? This has worked until now

- tried all conventions of throwing and catching the exceptions as : catch (OpenSSLException& e) , catch (...), catch (std::exception), and this has nothing to do with the problem
- this code is called from a seperate static library that my project uses (which I compile by myself and than link it)

Comment: Your specific problem aside, if you throw an instance, you should catch a reference to it, not a pointer. I understand you said you tried it like that too, I'm just saying your code as written there should definitely not work.

Comment: there are at least three separate "enable exception" checkboxes in your project's build settings.  Are they all set to ***YES***?

Comment: yes, 'enable exceptions' checkboxes (c++ and objectiveC) set to yes.  and I changed pointer part in the question